# Are there at least 17 different bases in which $(1,2,3)$ can be expressed as $(1,1,1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

The exercise in the title comes from a Linear algebra test for Physics students from my university. I tried to solve it like follows, but I'm sure there's a lot of more general statements that can prove this.

> The fact that the vector (which we shall call $\vec{v}$) can be
>   expressed as $(1,2,3)$ in the canonical base of $\mathbb{R}^3$ means
>   that $\vec{v}=1(1,0,0)+2(0,1,0)+3(0,0,1)$. If we wanted
>   $\vec{v}=(1,1,1)_{B'}$, a possibility would be a certain base $B'$ in which
>   $\vec{v}=(1,0,0)+(0,2,0)+(0,0,3)=(1,2,3)$. But we can
>   change that base in a particular way so that $v$ can still be expressed
>   as $(1,1,1)_{B'}$. It can be done like this:
>
> $$B'=\{(1,0,n),(0,2,-n),(0,0,3)\}, n\in\mathbb{R}$$
>
> Since there's an infinite number of real numbers, we can assure that
>   there are at least 17 bases $B'$ in which $(1,2,3)$ can be expressed
>   as $(1,1,1)_{B'}$.

How would you solve it? Can you think of a more general way?

**Note:** this exercise comes from a freshman course of Linear algebra and is worth 7.5% of the final grade of a midterm which is supposed to take 2.5 hours to complete, so please, as we say in my country, *don't kill flies with cannon fire*. Use, if possible, the tools a student would have in that situation.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  If $\vec v = (1,1,1)$ in that basis then we must have $\alpha =1, \beta =2, \gamma =3$, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my attempt to find an answer, following my particular line of reasoning. If $\alpha=1,\beta=2,\gamma=3$, then $B'=\{(1,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,3)\}$, and by changing two coordinates that will cancel out each other (like adding a $+n$ and $-n$ in the first and second vector) we can assure that there's an infinite number of bases that can express the vector $(1,2,3)$ as $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Of course I can vary $n$.  Then I agree, but it is very confusingly worded.  Why bother with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$?  They serve no role other than to confuse the reader.

Comment: You're right, I just copied what I had in my notebook, which I wrote as I thought about the different paths I could follow (so I was trying to be more general). I'm gonna edit my solution for clarity.

Comment: As another sort of approach:  start with any three points in general position on the unit sphere.  They define a basis for $\mathbb R^3$.  Order them arbitrarily.  Then in that bases $\vec v =(a,b,c)$ and, again generically, we can suppose that none of those are $0$.  Then scaling by $\frac 1a, \frac 1b, \frac 1c$ we get a basis in which $\vec v = (1,1,1)$ .

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks exactly right. If you wanted to put it a more formal way, you might say:

Let $c$ be any number, and consider the vectors:

$$b_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\c\end{bmatrix}\quad b_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\-c\end{bmatrix}\quad b_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

1. These vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$, and therefore constitute a basis. To prove this, it's enough to show how to make the three standard basis vectors out of the $b_i$. And indeed,
   $$e_1 = b_1 - c/3\,b_3$$
   $$e_2 = (b_2 + c/3 b_3)/2 $$
   $$e_3 = b_3/3$$
2. The vector $\vec{v} \equiv 1e_1 + 2e_2 + 3e_3$ can be expressed as $1 b_1 + 1b_2 + 1b_3$ in this basis.

   Indeed, using the standard basis to represent these in matrix form, we have that: $$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\c\end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\-c\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$$
   by cancellation, as required.
3. Because each choice of $c$ yields a different basis set, it is clear that there is an infinite number of possible bases with this property, and in particular at least 17.

Comment: Thanks for your input, that looks more general but still conveys the same meaning with the tools a student of that course would have :)